# How to pass navigation props to react arrow function outside of default class that returns text with on press navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-props, react-component

React Native Expo App:

In render of my default class I map from an array that calls an arrow function outside of the class to return a line of text for each object. I would like to pass the navigation prop through so that on press of that text will navigate to another screen.

My navigation is set up correct as it is called from a touchable opacity elsewhere in render to navigate to another screen.

I have stripped this back quite a bit but hopefully enough to explain:

```
const CustomDialogContent = ({name, ip, navigate}) => {
    return (
        <Text onPress={navigate('Webview')}>
            {name} ({ip})
        </Text>
    )
}

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component { 
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            devices: [],
            name: '',
            ip: '',
        };
    }
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'App',
    };
    render() {
        const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
        return (   
            <View style={container}>
                <Dialog                   
                    <DialogContent>
                        {this.state.devices.map((device) => {
                            return (
                                <CustomDialogContent name={device.name} ip={device.ip} navigation={navigate}/>
                            );}
                    </DialogContent>
                </Dialog>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Instead of taking me to the screen I get navigate is undefined. I have also tried this which threw undefined is not an object:

```
const CustomDialogContent = ({name, ip}) => {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    return (
        <Text onPress={navigate('Webview')}>
            {name} ({ip})
        </Text>
    )
}
```

I then tried this which returned navigate is not a function:

```
const CustomDialogContent = ({name, ip, navigate}) => {
    return (
        <Text onPress={() => {navigate('Webview')}}>
            {name} ({ip})
        </Text>
    )
}
```

Apologies if I am missing something quite basic I am a junior and completely new to react

Final solution with credit to @LonelyCpp:

```
const CustomDialogContent = props => {
    return (
      <Text onPress={() => {props.navigation('Webview');}}>
        {props.name} ({props.ip}) 
      </Text>
    );
};

<CustomDialogContent name={device.name} ip={device.ip} navigation={navigate}/>
```

Comment: It's a typo here `{name, ip, navigation}` it should be `navigation` not `navigate`

Comment: Is that not resolved from the following in the first example:

render() {const {navigate} = this.props.navigation; ... return ( <CustomDialogContent name={device.name} ip={device.ip} navigation={navigate}/>. And in the second example from: const CustomDialogContent = ({name, ip}) => { const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;

Comment: No, because want you are trying to is called destructuring in javascript here read [this](https://dev.to/sarah_chima/object-destructuring-in-es6-3fm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

props are like variable assignments. You've done `navigation={navigate}` which means in `CustomDialogContent` gets the function as `props.navigation`

this should work -

```
const CustomDialogContent = (props) => {
    const navigate = props.navigation; // no {}
    return (
        <Text onPress={()=>navigate('Webview')}>
            {name} ({ip})
        </Text>
    )
}
```

edit : removed `this` since its a functional component

Comment: Thanks LonelyCpp I have tried a few variations of this but it throws navigate is not a function...  navigate is undefined. I seem to missing something fundamental here :-/

Comment: make sure `this.props.navigation` in `HomeScreen` is not undefined. If it is, react-navigation is not configured properly

Comment: This is whats confusing, I have this else where in homescreen render and it works just fine: <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigate('Printer')}

Comment: Seems like everything works fine for me. Here's an expo snack with the complete code - https://snack.expo.io/HyfH0mXYS

Comment: Yes it does work! I had tweaked some previous code trying to fix it that interfered with your code. Thanks so much I have been stressing over this simple issue, however the props thing is now much more obvious so I can use it more appropriately going forward :)